# Issue with jumping to hyperlinks using IDs

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky

I am creating a navbar that when one of the 'a' tags are clicked on, the website jumps to that section.

My issue is that I have a sticky navbar that has a black background, therefore when I jump to the section ID, the navbar covers the section title text.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue through any means (Or by using waypoints)?

(I don't believe my code is needed to envision what my design looks like but I will supply it if required)

Comment: I believe I know what you require. if I were you I'd add a link above where you want the user to be directed so when they're directed there the navbar won't be in the way of titles, text etc. (also, give the link a visibility: hidden;)

Comment: I've actually just added a div and put the ID for the page to scroll to, it appears to be working, just a couple issues with padding/margin but nothing that I can't resolve.

Now how would I add smooth scrolling? I've had a look around on the internet and most of the tutorials appear to be outdated. Has anything changed with that regard?

Comment: Never mind lol, I found a working version of smooth scroll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a div just above where I wanted the page to jump to when clicked on. This worked for me. Thanks to @billy.farrol for the idea!